# Firebase and Postgres data sync

Tags: database, postgresql, firebase, nosql, data-synchronization

I have a mobile app whose data is currently maintained in firebase. And there is postgres db as well.(Both schema are different) I need to sync the data between the databases.
Currently all i can think of is, getting the data dump and use a script to update manually.  Is there any other better approach?

Comment: I don't think any other options. You can go ahead and create the the script. Let the community knows about what you're doing just open source it.